# what mediaquery sizes for responsive design?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

what are common media query sizes for responsive design in CSS, I need to responsive design  only for desktop, laptop, tablet and mobile.
please give me solution

Advance Thanks

Comment: Please research, try to do something and then ask for help when you run into a problem.

Comment: Worry more about what suits your design than what other people use.

Comment: i know about media queries, but more sizes are there..., I need which sizes are must need for media query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(width x Height)

Mobile portrait (320x480)

Mobile landscape (480x320)

Small tablet portrait (600x800)

Small tablet landscape (800x600)

Tablet portrait (768x1024)

Tablet landscape (1024x768)

Desktop bigger than (1024)

Answer (score 2):

Extra small devices Phones ( <768px )

Small devices Tablets ( ≥768px )

Medium devices Desktops ( ≥992px )

Large devices Desktops ( ≥1200px )

[CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)

http://www.w3.org/

[Media queries in bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)